# How to solve a "can not be resolved to a variable" error in Java?

Tags: java

i was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why my program keeps telling me the seperate_numbers can not be resolved to a variable. Also what type would i have to assign Seperate_number to make this program work. it must contain the two method headers public static void seperate_number(int integer) and public static int intGetNum.

Thanks for any help

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deprey_J_prog1
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int main_Number;
        main_Number =  intGetNum();
        Seperate_number = main_Number;
    }

    static int num, b, a, integer;

    public static int intGetNum()
    {
        int ret_val = 0;
        System.out.print("please enter a 5 integer number");
        integer = console.nextInt();
        return ret_val;
    }

    public static void Seperate_number(int integer)
    {
        for (a = 1; a <=5; a++)
        {
            for (b= 1; b <= a; b++)
                num = ((integer % 10) / 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A five digit number, you mean? What are you trying to do with it after it gets entered? Write out the digits?

Comment: your indentation is quite bad :(

Comment: I am suppose to take a 5 digit number and separate the number into the individual digits separated by three spaces each

Answer (score 8):

`Seperate_number` is declared as a method and you are trying to use it as a variable.

Also, please get familiar with Java's naming and formatting conventions.

Comment: @flup That document is 14 years old now and, although many basic things are still valid, I don't stand behind many others.

Comment: So do you have a better link for him then?

Answer (score 3):

The subject is : *How to solve a “can not be resolved to a variable” error in Java?*

If you want to remove the compilation error, Just declare the variable :

```
int Seperate_number = main_Number;
```

The question is not that clear for me, if something else needs to be achieve then this may not be the solution.

Comment: Guys, why are you downvoting? This is a right recommendation.

Comment: @ay89 , Can you show me where in Java spec you cannot define a local variable with the same name as a method ?

Comment: @ay89 thats not going to give any problem to you. you can use same name to method and variable. The main problem here is poor naming conventions used by user.

Comment: Helping out with +1 :) Yes, I don't see any problem with your answer. The OP is mixing up local variables and methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
Seperate_number = main_Number;
```

here is the problem. You can not assign a value to method.

Comment: Does that remove his compilation error or makes his code to atleast run ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `Seperate_number` instead of trying to assign to it.

```
Seperate_number(main_Number);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Seperate_number` is declared as method.

So change the name like: `int otherVariableName` or use the method like this `Seperate_number(main_Number)`